# Rate of change of an infinite step function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x) = \log \lfloor e^x \rfloor.$$
Everywhere it exists, $f'(x)= 0$. However, as $x$ increases, the graph of $f(x)$ quickly converges (in some sense) to the graph of $y=x$. Is there some precise sense in which we can say that the rate of change of $f(x)$ approaches $1$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: There are many ways you can say that. I think it depends on what you'll do with it afterwards. For example, you can say $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(2x) - f(x)}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @Tunococ Your example is certainly interesting, but it seems decidedly non-local. Are you aware of anything similar that would relate, say, $(\log \lfloor e^x \rfloor)^2$ to $2x$?

Comment: I can try to come up with another notion, but I can tell you it may not be very useful because I don't know what you want to do with it afterwards. Here's my other guess. Suppose we pick some $p \ge 1$ and define $n_{x,\epsilon}(f) = \int_x^{x+\epsilon} |f(x)|^p dx$. I say that the limit of $f$ as $x \to \infty$ is a continuous function $g$ such that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \lim_{x\to\infty} n_{x,\epsilon}(f - g) = 0$. (If you want the derivative, just put $g'$ instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x\}=x-[x]$ be the fractional part of $x$.

Then what? Then the function in question is

$$\log(e^x-\{e^x\})$$

But $0\le\{x\}<1$ always, so our function--by monotonicity of the log function--satisfies the inequality

$$x-\log 2=\log\left(e^x-{e^x\over 2}\right)\le \log(e^x-1)\le f(x)\le \log(e^x)=x$$

Which is a VERY crude estimate, but it does the job still, wonderfully well to show that the values of $x$ and $f(x)$ has difference bounded by $\log 2$.

**Edit:** Why not improve this a bit? Just for kicks and to get real convergence. For $x>\log n$ we have $e^x>n$ so that $e^x/n>1$ and

$$x-\log\left(1+{1\over n-1}\right)=\log\left(e^x-{e^x\over n}\right)\le\log(e^x-1)\le f(x)\le x$$

here clearly the error term goes to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I think you mean $x - \log 2$ in your first bound.

Comment: Why? $\log(2e^x)=\log 2+x$.

Comment: Should $\log(e^x - \{e^x\})$ not be bounded below by $\log(e^x - 1)$? Try plotting the two functions; you'll see what I mean.

Comment: ah, I see, I actually got things backwards, I'll fix that, but the essential quality will remain, including that a change in one necessarily forces a VERY similar change in the other. One second to edit.

Comment: @DavidZhang fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the distribution $T_f \in \def\D{\mathcal D}\D'(\def\R{\mathbb R}\R)$ given by $f$, namely
$$ T_f(\phi) = \int_{\R} f(x)\,\phi(x) \, dx, \quad \phi \in \D(\R) $$
Then 
$$ T_f' = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \bigl(\log(k+1) - \log k\bigr) \delta_{\log k} $$
Let $\phi \in \D(\R)$, and let $\tau_x$ denote the shift by $x$, that is $\tau_x\phi(y) = \phi(y-x)$, and $T_1$ the distribution corresponding to $x\mapsto 1$, then for any $\phi\in \D(\R)$:
\begin{align*}
  (T_f')(\tau_x \phi)
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \bigl(\log(k+1) - \log k\bigr) \phi(\log k - x) 
\end{align*}
Now let $[a,b]$ denote some intervall containing the support of $\phi$, then 
$$ (T_f')(\tau_x\phi) = \sum_{k: a+x\le \log k \le b+x} \bigl(\log(k+1) - \log k\bigr) \phi(\log k - x) $$
Now note that for $x\to\infty$, the fineness of the partition $\{\log k - x\mid a+x\le \log k \le b+x\}$ of $[a,b]$ tends to $0$, hence 
$$ (\tau_{-x}T_f')(\phi) =  (T_f')(\tau_x\phi) \to \int_a^b \phi(y)\,dy = \int_\R\phi(y)\,dy = T_1(\phi)$$
Altogether this gives $\tau_{-x}T_f' \to T_1$ in $\D'(\R)$. 
So in this sense, the derivative converges to 1 for $x\to\infty$.